# Docker-php-ext-install vs apt install?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo

I'm trying to install pdo-mysql to PHP container
I tried to install it using command line as:

```
apt install pdo pdo_mysql
```

but the extension not installed and provide a lot of errors.

But When I use

```
docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

The extension was installed successfully

So what is the difference between them, and when must use each of them?

Answer (score 4):

`apt` is a softwar for Debian-like Linux distributions to manage packages. It can install pre-compiled packages for your distribution. It can do it for PHP-related packages as well. If you installed PHP using `apt` you can also install additional packages for it like that:

`sudo apt install -y php-pdo-mysql`

The exact package name will depend on the distribution you used and/or how you installed PHP in the first place.

The `docker-php-ext-install` is a special shell script in the official PHP Docker image where PHP was installed from the source. It will compile and install the necessary extensions.

Since you are using this Docker image `docker-php-ext-install` is the way to go.

To sum it up: it all depends on how PHP was installed in your Docker image in the first place. If a package manager was used - then `apt` is the way to go. If you use the official PHP Docker image it compiles PHP from the source code and provides a shortcut to compile additional extensions using `docker-php-ext-install`.